# Namespace issue in Model in Laravel - Package Development

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php

I am developing a package in `laravel` which uses model for CRUD operations.

I have put it up in [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/zusamarehan/tourify) as well, but when I try to install it in laravel application and visit a route defined by the package, it says

> Class 'Zusamarehan\Tourify\Model\Tourifies' not found

The following is the folder structure of my package

- rehan

  - tourify

    - src

      - assets
      - database
      - Http
      - Model

        - Tourifies.php
      - resources
      - routes
      - TourifyServiceProvider.php
      - composer.json

The following is the contents of my `Tourifies.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Zusamarehan\Tourify\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tourifies extends Model
{

}
```

The following is my `composer.json` file

```
{
    "name": "zusamarehan/tourify",
    "description": "A Package for adding Tour/Help to your Laravel Projects.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "tour", "tourify", "product-tour", "product-help"],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "zusamarehan",
            "email": "zrehan286@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Zusamarehan\\tourify\\TourifyServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zusamarehan\\tourify\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

The Model class is not loading I suppose? I am not sure.

Can someone point out the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Zusamarehan\\tourify\\": "src"` in your `composer.json` is wrong. Needs uppercase `T`. Looking at mine I also have a trailing `/` after `src` so you can try that as well.
You have the same lowercase `t` in the provider.

Comment: Let me try this and get pack. Btw, where to look up your composer file?

Comment: You can pretty much look up any package. First one in my history, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-feed/blob/master/composer.json#L45

Answer (score 2):

The namespaces in your classes use `Zusamarehan\Tourify`, however, in your `composer.json` you've used `Zusamarehan\tourify`. These should match.

You'll need to update your `composer.json` file so that the namespaces uses the correct case:

```
{
    "name": "zusamarehan/tourify",
    "description": "A Package for adding Tour/Help to your Laravel Projects.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "tour", "tourify", "product-tour", "product-help"],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "zusamarehan",
            "email": "zrehan286@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Zusamarehan\\Tourify\\TourifyServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zusamarehan\\Tourify\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try and get back